# Export function in a dll but still use it in other files within the dll project

Tags: dllexport

We are in the process of refactoring some of our code base. At the moment we have many dll's in which most are single C/C++ files. Each of these have a #define in them that allows the compiler to either export (if building the DLL) or import (if using the function from the dll from another application or another DLL).
As an example we may have the following in the .c or .cpp file:

```
#define PROJECT1_DLL_BUILD
```

And then in the .h file we have the following:

```
#ifdef PROJECT1_DLL_BUILD
#define PROJECT1_DLL_LINK __declspec ( dllexport )
#else
#define PROJECT1_DLL_LINK __declspec ( dllimport )
#endif
```

And then later in the .h file we have:

```
PROJECT1_DLL_LINK void function1(int param1);
PROJECT1_DLL_LINK void function2(int param1);
...
```

Now we are combining many of these individual DLL projects into a single one and I'm having an issue.
The issue is that function1 above needs to still be exported but also needs to be used in another file within the DLL project.
I am using Visual Studio 2019 and I get the LNK4217 warning. (Our internal company policy states we can have no errors or warnings when compiling). Following the link given in the warning it suggests adding the /CLR option. When I add the /CLR option I then get the C4747 warning. And after following the link and reviewing that information it recommends that I get rid of the /CLR option.

What are my options such that I can export the function out of my new combined DLL and also use the function in other files within this same DLL? All with compiling with no warnings.

All my search results seem to point me to how to export a function from a DLL.

I attempted to switch to using a .def file for the new combined DLL but this is not how our company prefers to export functions.
If I get rid of the "PROJECT1_DLL_LINK" in front of "void function1(int param1); it will compile but then that function will no longer get exported.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `#define PROJECT1_DLL_BUILD` for all the source files?